# Does $W^{1,1}(\Omega)^*$ contain a countable separating set?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to show that a weakly precompact subset $S$ of $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ is metrizable. If I am not mistaken, it is enough to show that $W^{1,1}(\Omega)^*$ contain a countable separating set.

> Is it the case that $W^{1,1}(\Omega)^*$ contains a countable separating set?

Alternatively, if there is another approach to show that $(S,w)$ is metrizable I'd love to know about it as well.

Comment: What do you mean by a separating set?

Comment: I meant a family of linear functionals that separates points of $W^{1,1}$. My current idea is to consider the fact that if $X=L^1$ then the family of characteristic functions of dyadic cubes works (identifying $(L^1)^*$ with $L^{\infty}$). Then the result should hopefully follow from from the isometric embedding of $W^{1,1}$ into the products of copies of $L^1$. I haven't worked out the details yet though.

Comment: Generally, if $X$ is a separable Banach space, consider a countable dense subset $\{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of the unit sphere of $X$ (since some people call the ball "sphere", let me clarify that I speak of $\{ x \in X : \lVert x\rVert = 1\}$; and I assume infinite dimension - it's trivial in finite dimension). For each $n$, choose $f_n \in X'$ with $\lVert f_n\rVert = 1$ and $f_n(x_n) > \frac{1}{2}$. Then $\{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a separating set. For, if $\lVert x\rVert = 1$ there is an $n$ with $\lVert x-x_n\rVert < 1/4$. Then $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert > 1/4$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Together with your previous comment on the other thread, we can conclude that any relative weakly compact subset of a separable Banach space $X$ is metrizable (in the weak topology), is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And the metrisability of relatively weakly compact subsets (in the weak topology) is also given in _some_ non-separable Banach spaces (like $L^{\infty}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your idea in the comments just works.

First let's show that we can find a countable separating set $D \subset L^\infty(\Omega)$ for $L^1(\Omega)$. Define $\mathcal{A}$ to be the set of rectangles in $\Omega$ with rational endpoints and let 
$$D = \{ \mathbb{1}_A : A \in \mathcal{A}\} \subset L^\infty(\Omega).$$
Since $\mathcal{A}$ generates the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, by a standard monotone class argument, 
$$\int_A f \, d \mu = 0 \text{ for all } A \in \mathcal{A} \implies \int_A f \, d \mu = 0 \text{ for all } A \in \mathcal{B}(\Omega).$$
In particular, this implies that if $f,g \in L^1(\Omega)$ and $\int_A f \, d \mu = \int_A g \, d \mu$ for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$ then $f = g$. This means that $D$ separates points in $L^1(\Omega)$. Clearly $D$ is also countable.

Now, recall that $W^{1,1}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^{1}(\Omega)$ and so by taking duals $L^\infty(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W^{1,1}(\Omega)^*$ and so we can regard $D$ as a subset of $W^{1,1}(\Omega)^*$. Then it is clear that $D$ is the desired countable separating set.